# Including polygons as part of network for ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, network-analyst

I am creating a pedestrian walking network of a downtown area.

I am digitizing line segments for paths and sidewalks, but I need to incorporate parking lots into my analysis.

So far, I have been creating multiple lines through parking lots to represent possible routes that a pedestrian might take through the lot.

This is tedious, and somewhat random.

I have my parking lots as a polygon feature class.

Is there any way for me to include these polygons in the network by snapping my walking network lines to the parking lot polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in water system management network analysis we had to have a stream centerline for each "pond" polygon, to hold the network information for the pond.
HTH

Comment: Yes, IMO that would be the way to go. The centerlines would connect all paths connected to the polygon, so it would be possible to "route" through the parking lot/polygon.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your polygon to line add to your network and use the snap tolerance setting
[image]

source:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000003w000000.htm